# Get the PHP files in some folder

Tags: php

I have a folder that contains 5 pages, and I want to get for each page it's link, it's creation date and it's title.

For now I do it as the following :

```
<?php
    function getActus()
    {
        return array(

                $message1 = array(
                    'date'  => filectime("news/news1.php"),
                    'titre' => "News 1",
                    'url'   => "/Serie_4/ex3/news/news1.php"
                 ),

                $message2 = array(
                    'date'  => filectime("news/news2.php"),
                    'titre' => "News 2",
                    'url'   => "/Serie_4/ex3/news/news2.php"
                 ),

                $message3 = array(
                    'date'  => filectime("news/news3.php"),
                    'titre' => "News 3",
                    'url'   => "/Serie_4/ex3/news/news3.php"
                 ),

                $message4 = array(
                    'date'  => filectime("news/news4.php"),
                    'titre' => "News 4",
                    'url'   => "/Serie_4/ex3/news/news4.php"
                 ),

                $message5 = array(
                    'date'  => filectime("news/news5.php"),
                    'titre' => "News 5",
                    'url'   => "/Serie_4/ex3/news/news5.php"
                 )
            );
    }
?>
```

I want to do that dynamically, because sometimes I don't know how much page I have on that folder.

How can I get the files that are in some folder.

I also want to get the title for each page, and I mean by the title the one wich is between `<title>` and `</title>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve a list of files in a directory, check out: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php

To retrieve the modification time for each file:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

To extract the title from a page:
http:// stackoverflow.com/questions/13510124/regular-expression-to-get-page-title

I prefer the asad's anwser:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$titles = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title");
echo $titles->item[0]->nodeValue;
```

But you will want to load from a file, not a string: http:// php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php